# Are the electrical issues of the Scenic II series fixed in the Scenic III series?

Tags: electrical, renault, reliability, scenic

I am considering buying a second-hand `Scenic III` with high mileage, but am concerned about electrical issues.

According to Renault on the [Renault Forums](http://www.renaultforums.co.uk/17-electronics/70682-important-info-scenic-2-dashboard-failures.html) in 2009:

> ... some owners have experienced problems with the Scenic II instrument panel losing the display. This model was launched in 2003 and, since then, 159,000 have been sold in the UK.
>
> We have investigated these cases of the instrument panel losing the display and found that they chiefly relate to 2004 and 2005 Scenic II models.

Since then, the `Scenic III` came out.

#### Have the above mentioned issues has really been taken care of in the Scenic III series?

[Reliability Index](http://www.reliabilityindex.com/reliability/search/211) shows that 45% of the issues on `Renault Scenic` are still "electrical" problems.

Comment: Considering that a modern car is akin to a computer network equipped with wheels and windshield wipers, I suspect a whole slew of issues could reasonably accurately be described as "electrical" problems.